# Install FFmpeg with loudnorm filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to install FFmpeg with loudnorm filter in Ubuntu 14.04 
 
 1. Downloaded [FFmpeg 3.2.4](http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.2.4.tar.bz2) 
 2. Install [libeurl128](https://github.com/jiixyj/libebur128)
3. Configure it as follow:

> ./configure --cpu=native --enable-pthreads --enable-bzlib
>   --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-openssl --enable-libebur128

Tried the next command for test:

> ./ffmpeg -i udp_mpegts -vcodec copy -af loudnorm /tmp/test.ts

And received the following error:

> ./ffmpeg: symbol lookup error:  ./ffmpeg: undefined symbol:
>   ebur128_relative_threshold

Comment: libebur128 has been inducted within ffmpeg since Nov 12 2016. Get a binary or compile source after that. External lib not required,

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you! But I don't understand what need to do. I get a FFmpeg released version from 2017-02-10 and if I deleted --enable-libebur128 from configuration then I received the following error:[AVFilterGraph @ 0x21a18e0] No such filter: 'loudnorm'  Can you please explain it with more details?

Comment: Get a master branch source (https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2) or binary (http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), not a release version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Nov 12 2016, `libebur128` has been inducted within the base ffmpeg project, so the external library is not required.

Get a master branch source from https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 -- or -- a [binary](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).